Where else should I check for leak on 2016 Dodge caravan?
I had the engine replaced after I got the car for an oil leak and unfortunately it started leaking oil again. I put dye to see if I could find where the leak is coming from but I can't find a specific place. I tried checking the oil filter/color housing under the intake manifold and see a little dye and leak here but it doesn't seem like the housing is leaking.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The first thing I'd suggest is to get everything as clean as you can get it around where you are spotting the oil. It will make it easier to find the leak. Also remember, oil when leaking is like anything else, it drains downhill. If you see the oil, it has to be coming from somewhere above that.
